# TypeError: object is not a function at new <anonymous>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add 2 empty `person` objects to array and after populate it. Chrome complains `TypeError: object is not a function     at new <anonymous>`. What's wrong?

```
$scope.person = {
        firstName : '',
        lastName : '',
        dateOfBirth : '',
        sex : '',
        nationality : ''
    };
    $scope.persons = [];
    $scope.persons.push(new $scope.person); // error
    $scope.persons.push(new $scope.person);
```

Comment: Exactly what it says. `$scope.person` isn't a constructor function, so you can't create a new instance of it.

Comment: You seem to be trying to clone the object. Closing as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.persons.push(angular.copy($scope.person));
$scope.persons.push(angular.copy($scope.person));
```

you need a copy of a `person` object , you cant use `new` keyword with it

in java, you can use `class` to create a object, after creating a object you can deal with it, but you cant create a new object from the object. like wise `$scope.person` is a object. you cant use `new` keyword with it.